# How to render curves (or a faceless mesh)

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, wireframe

I'm experimenting with geometry nodes in Blender 3.1 alpha, and used the following spaghetti of nodes to draw a trefoil:

[image: geometry nodes]

The result is what I expect, shown in the viewport from the camera angle here:

[image: viewport]

Now I would like to render the result, either as a line as shown here, or as some thin tube with a usual material. A few things I've tried:

- Setting Object Data Properties » Geometry » Bevel » Depth — this doesn't seem to work when I use a Geometry Nodes modifier (it works with simple bezier curves without a modifier).
- Using the freestyle renderer — it won't render the edges, presumably because there are no faces attached.
- Attaching a face and then using the freestyle renderer — I can add a face using the "Fill Curve" node, but then it flattens the whole curve in the Z axes.

What I'd like is some sort of wireframe rendering that works with objects that have geometry nodes attached and no faces (because no face could be added due to the topology of the curve).

Comment: Blender 3.0 isn't due for release until next month, let alone 3.1 so you're unlikely to get an answer here for any unsupported experimental version.

Comment: Well, it's destructive but you could apply the *Geometry Nodes* modifier?

Comment: If this is maintained in the latest version of Blender, I would report it as a bug. The geometry beveling should work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DuarteFarrajotaRamos; I'll go ahead and report a bug.

Comment: Why not use a **Curve to Mesh** with a **Curve Circle** as Profile Curve?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the result in your case, but you could perhaps add a `Skin` modifier after the GeoNodes. On my (much simpler) test it works well enough

Comment: The `Skin` modifier is only available for mesh objects, and I'm adding my geometry nodes to a curve object, so the `Skin` modifier is not available. That said, I tried using a mesh as the base object, then the skin modifier is available, but not applied, even after applying the geometry nodes (!), I think this could be a bug. The problem only appears though when I don't use the `Group Input` node, and instead generate my own input using one of the primitives (e.g. `Mesh Line` or `Curve Line`). After applying the geometry node, adding a _new_ `Skin` modifier works.